# Displaying data through stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, select, stored-procedures

```
Create or replace procedure disp(pEMPLASTNAME varchar2)
IS
Row employee%rowtype;
begin
select * into row from employee where EMPLASTNAME=’pEMPLASTNAME’ ;
dbms_output.put_line('Name: '||Row.EMPID||' '|| Row.EMPNAME);
End;
/

BEGIN
disp(‘Mark’);
END;
/
```

Hello, I am trying to display data from a a table using stored procedures. The last name is passed as a parameter through the stored procedure and upon execution , the stored procedure should display all the rows which have the last name . Here is the error that i get; pls help! :-

```
SQL> BEGIN
disp('Mark');
END;
/
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "TEST.DISP", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of the quotes:

```
select * into row from employee where EMPLASTNAME=pEMPLASTNAME;
```

However, you may not have any data for that variable's value anyway (i.e. one day, it may happen)
That's why I recommend you catch the exception and treat it (see `EXCEPTION` block)

pd: it is a good practice to not use reserved words such as `row`. I recommend you name your variable another way.

Comment: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Comment: @Nidhin_toms, it means more than one employee have their last name like 'Mark'. This pl/sql block only allows one row to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a cursor to select all rows and then looping through the cursor to print the result:

```
Create or replace procedure disp(pEMPLASTNAME varchar2)
IS
Cursor row_select is
    select EMPID, EMPNAME from employee where emplastname = pEMPLASTNAME;
-- and whatever columns you need to print, using * isn't good practice

begin
for item in row_select loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Name: '||item.EMPID||' '|| item.EMPNAME);
end loop;
End;
/

BEGIN
disp(‘Mark’);
END;
/
```